# conan C++ ERROR: Unable to find Package in remotes

Tags: cmake, conan

I'm new to Conan. I tried to create a package and upload into remote (myconan-test). The package is in local cache and in remote.

Package in local

```
[user@dev build]$ conan search MyLib*
Existing package recipes:

MyLib/0.1@myself/Testing
```

Upload package to remote

```
[user@dev build]$ conan upload MyLib/0.1@myself/testing -r=myconan-test
Uploading to remote 'myconan-test':
Uploading MyLib/0.1@myself/testing to remote 'myconan-test'
Compressing conan_sources.tgz completed [3 files]
Uploading conanmanifest.txt completed [0.24k]
Uploaded conan recipe 'MyLib/0.1@myself/testing' to 'myconan-test': http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/artifactory/api/conan/conan-local
```

Now package is in remote

```
[user@dev build]$ conan search MyLib* -r=myconan-test
Existing package recipes:

MyLib/0.1@myself/testing
```

I created a consumer project that uses MyLib/0.1. But when I did: `conan install ..` I had an error like:

```
MyLib/0.1: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
MyLib/0.1: Trying with 'conan-center'...
MyLib/0.1: Trying with 'myconan-test'...
ERROR: Unable to find 'MyLib/0.1' in remotes
```

My conanfile.txt is

```
[requires]
MyLib/0.1

[generators]
gcc
cmake
txt

[imports]
bin, *.a -> ./bin # Copies all dll files from the package "bin" folder to my project "bin" folder
```

If I change the require to: MyLib/0.1@myself/testing. It works because it uses the package in cache. My question is how I can use the remote package. 
What is my error?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT---
After understanding how to call my package by adding MyLib/0.1@myself/testing. I can download the package from remote. But in the building step, I have an error:

```
[user@dev build]$ conan build ..
Using lockfile: '/home/user/Projects/consumer_MyLib/build/conan.lock'
Using cached profile from lockfile
conanfile.py: Running build()
-- Conan: called by CMake conan helper
-- Conan: Adjusting output directories
-- Conan: Using cmake global configuration
-- Conan: Adjusting default RPATHs Conan policies
-- Conan: Adjusting language standard
-- Conan: Checking correct version: 4.8
-- Conan: C++ stdlib: libstdc++
**CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "MyLib" which is not built by this
  project.**
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(consumer_MyLib CXX)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

add_executable(${project_name} example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${project_name}  ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 3):

The package reference in [conanfile.txt](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/using_packages/conanfile_txt.html?) is declared using its name, version, user and channel. Both user and channel are used as a namespace and they are important to the package reference. Besides that, Conan also supports package names without a namespace, thus we can have:

```
zlib/1.2.11
zlib/1.2.11@acme/stable
zlib/1.2.11@acme/testing
```

Here we have 3 packages, both are related to zlib/1.2.11, but they are different packages. The first doesn't have a namespace, however it's a valid package name and it's owned by [Conan Center Index](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/). The other 2 packages are provided by *acme*, but have different channels. Conan see each package reference as unique, so if you refer `zlib/1.2.11` in your conanfile.txt it will look for the first package only.

Now backing to your situation, you created the package `MyLib/0.1@myself/Testing`, and Conan search command returned it when using the regex, which is plausible because is a search command. However, when referring the package in your conanfile.txt, you have to use the complete reference which follows your package:

```
# conanfile.txt

[requires]
MyLib/0.1@myself/Testing

...
```

If you look for `MyLib/0.1` only, Conan will take it as a valid reference, and won't complete with your reference. There is no implicit deduction.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `@user/channel` part in your requires:

```
[requires]
MyLib/0.1@myself/testing
```

When you are uploading the packages, you probably want to add `--all` to make sure you upload the binary too:

```
conan upload MyLib/0.1@myself/testing -r=myconan-test --all
```

Check the [upload command](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/creator/upload.html) in the docs.

If you want to make sure that your cache doesn't have the package, do a `conan remove "*" -f`

Comment: Thank you verry much for your explication

Comment: I edited my question because I have an error in compilation "Cannot specify link libraries for target "MyLib" which is not built by this
  project.". I verified the MyLib.a is in the cache.

Comment: There is something missing. For example in cmake you write ``target_link_libraries(${project_name} PRIVATE ${CONAN_LIBS})``, and you are missing that private. It would be worth to post a new question, with updated information, as this is not a "package not found in remotes" anymore, but something more related to your build system. Please add in your new question the exact commands you are using to build too.

Comment: Thank you @drodi. I have posted a new question